# android php mysql, get table rowcount and show it on textview

Tags: javascript, php, android, eclipse

anyone i need help with my current problem,
so i created an app that could be used as login and register new account, i found the tutorial lately on internet and it run smoothly,

however i'm trying to count the table row evertime new account registered and show the number on textview, so i need help to figure out how to count the row in register.php file and get the value

here's my main activity class :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import subactivity.ProfilSekolah;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity {

 public static int fokus = 0;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Button btnRegistAccount;

    String level;
    TextView text;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);
        
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_action_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  
  
  btnRegistAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_regist_account);

  
    }
 
 
 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_utama, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_login) {
         if (Login.login_status.equals("true")){
          startActivity(new Intent(this, InfoLogin.class));
          finish();
         } else {
         startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
   finish();
         }
  }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void registerAccount(View v) {
     startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
 }
 
}
```

my main activity xml :

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.MenuUtama" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_action_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar" />
            
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_regist_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:onClick="registerAccount"
        android:text="Register"/>
     
          //try to show it here
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row Count"
        />
            

</LinearLayout>
```

my JSONParser class :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

 static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
 
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
 
    }
    
    
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;
            
            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            
            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }
    
 
    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
 
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
 
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
 
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           
 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", json);
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
 
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
 
    }
}
```

my register class :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 private EditText user, pass, levelakses, jabatan;
 private Button  mRegister;

  // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script
    //using my phone as emulator
    private static final String REGIST_URL = "http://192.168.1.110/smkkimmanuel2/register.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

  user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
  pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
  levelakses = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.levelakses);
  jabatan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jabatan);

  mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
  mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   new CreateUser().execute();
 }

 class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
  boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            String level_akses = levelakses.getText().toString();
            String jabat = jabatan.getText().toString();
            
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("level_akses", level_akses));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jabatan", jabat));
                

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       REGIST_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                 Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                 finish();
                 return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                 Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                 return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

  }
  /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
             Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

 }

}
```

my register account xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightblue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="Type Username"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="Type Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/levelakses"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="Level Access 1-3"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/jabatan"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="Type Occupation"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/btn_register"
            android:textColor="@color/lightblue" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and now my config.php :

```js
<?php

 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $host = "localhost";
 $dbname = "smkkimmanuel2";

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try 
    { 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
     
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
     
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
     
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    } 
     
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
     
    session_start(); 

?>
```

last is my register.php :

```js
<?php

/*
Our "config.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //If the username or password is empty when the user submits
    //the form, the page will die.
    //Using die isn't a very good practice, you may want to look into
    //displaying an error message within the form instead.  
    //We could also do front-end form validation from within our Android App,
    //but it is good to have a have the back-end code do a double check.
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        
        
        // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Mohon Lengkapi Username dan Password.";
        
        //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
        //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
        //app will parse
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else if (empty($_POST['level_akses']) || empty($_POST['jabatan'])) {
        
        
        // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Mohon Lengkapi Level Akses dan Jabatan.";
        
        //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
        //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
        //app will parse
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    
    //if the page hasn't died, we will check with our database to see if there is
    //already a user with the username specificed in the form.  ":user" is just
    //a blank variable that we will change before we execute the query.  We
    //do it this way to increase security, and defend against sql injections
    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM user_id WHERE username = :user";
    //now lets update what :user should be
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );
    
    //Now let's make run the query:
    try {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        
        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    
    //fetch is an array of returned data.  If any data is returned,
    //we know that the username is already in use, so we murder our
    //page
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("This username is already in use");
        
        //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    
    //If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
    //create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
    //Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_id ( username, password, level_akses, jabatan ) VALUES ( :user, :pass, :level_akses, :jabatan ) ";
    
    //Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':pass' => $_POST['password'],
  ':level_akses' => $_POST['level_akses'],
  ':jabatan' => $_POST['jabatan']
    );
    
    //time to run our query, and create the user
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        
        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    
    //If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
    //a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
    //redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
    //json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
    //the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    
    //for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
    //header("Location: login.php"); 
    //die("Redirecting to login.php");
    
    
} else {
?>
 <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: If login worked smoothly then why don't you try yourself to understand the API calls and parsing the response?

Comment: That's too much of code you shared!

Comment: @Paresh any reference where should i learn that? And sorry if that's too much, i'm just trying to be clear with my question

Comment: What do you want to learn? You already have enough code, just look at the existing code and at least try to learn and do some experiment with the existing code!

Comment: If you have a login code then can't you learn implementing other APIs?

Comment: Oka~y, i already understand the existing code and i understand about parsing response but i'm not fully understand about this, sorry if my question is kinda "noob" cause i'm new at this anyway, thanks.